# Do the scriptures recommend not leaving one's home empty stomach in the morning?

Tags: belief, rituals, practice, food

I have heard Elders say that we mustn't leave the home in the morning on an empty stomach for that results in ill-fortunes and bad-omens for the upcoming day. The common reasoning given by them is it is written in shastras.

Is this belief or practice supported by scriptures?

Comment: Too many questions regarding 'belief' today :D

Comment: Actually, yeah. There are so many of those beliefs, I can actually ask, but it may seem like spamming, so, I'll ask slowly :p @LSSJBroly